# Is there a gem similar to active admin for user views in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

just curious if there's a gem similar to ActiveAdmin for viewing data when simply logged in as current_user.  Having the filters, and sorting, for any column already there is awfully nice, and if I don't have to reinvent the wheel, I don't want to.

Just checking, really.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I've come across unfortunately.

However, if you're just looking for a way to provide some interactivity to a set of data, the `jquery-datatables-rails` gem may do what you need (this is in fact just a gem wrapper for the datatables JS library from [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/)):

https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

Also, there's a railscast on using it here -
http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

Hope that helps!

Comment: how can we use jquery datatables with activeadmin?